# Does this kind of "partition" have a name?

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity, terminology, polyhedra

Consider a convex polyhedron $A$. Assume we have subsets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ of $A$ that are themselves covex polyhedra and are mutually disjoint except maybe sharing an edge, and that their union gives $A$.
A simple example would be $A=[0,10]$ with $A_1=[0,3]$, $A_2=[3,6]$ and $A_3=[6,10]$ (observe $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint except for a common extreme point, and so are $A_2$ and $A_3$, and their union gives $A$).

What do we call this sort of partition-like subdivision of $A$ (in addition to a "cover")?

Comment: It's a pure math problem and should be asked on math.stackexchange. if you just want a name I think it's additionally called decomposition

Comment: There is a [dissection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissection) tag at math.stackexchange, but the polyhedra are not always restricted to be convex.

Comment: I reposted on math.stackexchange (I hope without breaking any rules)

Comment: @pele of course not. It's just that the other site may have more active experts interested in pure math questions. So ensuring you've posted there as well.

Comment: Cross-posted on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632957/595412).

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is often referred to as a "[tesselation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation)" or "tiling". I believe they are studied a fair bit by people working on computer graphics.